# Lodash filter out rougue items from object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, lodash

I am creating an object from a json file events.json using lodash map and uniqby.

Very rarely I get an event that has a country other than "United Kingdom". I don't need them in the results, how would I go about 'not mapping' the events that are not in the "United Kingdom". Thanks

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var data = require('./events.json')

var newEventList = _.uniqBy(data.events,'id').map(events => ({
    id: events.id ,
    name: events.name ,
    venue: events.venue.name ,
    address: events.place.location.street + " " + events.place.location.city + " " + events.place.location.zip + " " + events.place.location.country
}));
```

I have looked at _.filter but am not sure of where to use it within the map function.

Comment: Use `filter` first.

Comment: I was hoping it could all be done on the same line as the UniqBy & Map.

Comment: It can - `.filter((event) => event.place.location.country === "United Kingdom")`

Comment: Sorry for noob question but would it go something like `var newEventList = _.uniqBy(data.events,'id').filter((event) => event.place.location.country === "United Kingdom") .map(events => ({ `      ?

Comment: @PaulLeppard Yes, that's it

Comment: What a star. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter before or after map. But before map it will be more useful.

```
var newEventList = _.uniqBy(data.events,'id').filter(event => event.place.location.country === 'United Kingdom').map(event => ({
    id: event.id ,
    name: event.name ,
    venue: event.venue.name ,
    address: event.place.location.street + " " + event.place.location.city + " " + event.place.location.zip + " " + event.place.location.country
}));
```

But the question is why you need uniq by id? Usually id is a property that should be uniq

Comment: Thanks.. Yeah you would have thought but the data file I have sometimes has duplicates in it which I needed to remove.

Comment: Credit does go to @user184994 for getting in with the comments above, but thanks all the same.